# Using DI to set a property in an NLog Target

Tags: dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, nlog

I'm using NLog and have a custom target. I'd like to inject a dependency into this target. The dependency has already been registered in a Unity container. I'm this in an MVC application and the DI container is being setup in Application_Start

There is an answer to a similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/a/9704442 but I'm not sure how to apply this to my code

Answer (score 0):

The important part is to set this custom handler, this will be called for the types used by nlog.
Make sure that you initialize the nlog after this is done and the dependencies are registered

```
register your instances
.....
ConfigurationItemFactory.Default.CreateInstance = (Type type) =>
{
    object instance;
    if(unity/ninject/etc.TryResolve(type, out instance))
      return instance;
    else
      return Activator.CreateInstance(type); //this is to support the other types that come with NLog
};
......
 ConfigureNLog(...)
```