# Send event from NLog target using AppccelerateEventBroker

Tags: c#, ninject, nlog, event-bus, ninject-extensions

I want to put log messages to console and part of UI of my app simultaneously. But i cant find a way to do it with ninject.

I have a logger injected by ninject, and it perfectly make output to console and custom target. But I can't subscribe target to event broker because target initialization was outside ninject life-cycle.

Can anyone make some advice with this? How i can display logs in my UI?

Comment: did you have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6018721/nlog-dependency-injection-for-custom-targets ?

Comment: Thank you very much!

NLog.Config.ConfigurationItemFactory.Default.CreateInstance = (type) => kernel.TryGet(type);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to **BatteryBackupUnit** i found how to resolve this situation.
First of all We need to inject logs target to kernel
`kernel.Bind<IMyTarget>().To<MyTarget>();`
And then make a custom instantiation method
`NLog.Config.ConfigurationItemFactory.Default.CreateInstance = (type) => kernel.TryGet(type);`