# How can I get NLog to inject dependencies into a target?

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, autofac, nlog

I have a custom NLog log target class that looks like this:

```
public class MyTarget : AsyncTaskTarget
{
   public MyTarget() {}

   public MyTarget(INeedThisThingToFunction thing)
   {
      Thing = thing;
   }

   public INeedThisThingToFunction Thing { get; set; }

   public override Task WriteAsyncTask(LogEventInfo logEvent, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   {
      Thing.Use();
      return null;
   }
}
```

I cannot figure out how to ensure that the second constructor gets called. I've done this in Program.cs:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
   var host = CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build();
   ConfigureLogging(host.Services.GetAutofacRoot());
   LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger().Info("Hi mom");
   host.Run();
}

private static void ConfigureLogging(IComponentContext container) {
   ConfigurationItemFactory.Default.CreateInstance = type =>
   {
      if (type != typeof(MyTarget) return Activator.CreateInstance(type);
      var thing = new ThingTheTargetNeedsToFunction();
      return new MyTarget(thing);
   }
   LogManager.Configuration.Reload();
}
```

I've tried a number of other things, too, but that comes the closest to doing something. When `LogManager.Configuration.Reload()` is called, the `CreateInstance` code fires; but when the `Info` method fires, the `Thing` property on the target is null.

Is there a better way to do this? Like, a way that works?

Using .NET Core 3, NLog, Autofac.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NLog: Dependency Injection for custom Targets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6018721/nlog-dependency-injection-for-custom-targets)

Comment: There is a wiki-page: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Dependency-injection-with-NLog

Comment: I was hoping to avoid the service locator pattern, as to me it seems to defeat the purpose of DI. I'd love it if I could register my log targets and have Autofac instantiate them properly. Or NLog.

Comment: @DavidBraverman Right now the NLog Dependency Injection support is rather limited. Mainly because logging is usually setup before dependency container is fully loaded. But work is being done to improve the situation, so custom targets can resolve custom dependencies during initialization (instead of constructor-parameters). And hopefully automatically delay the initialization until custom dependency is available. And hopefully also queue LogEvents so they can be written after initialization has been performed succesfully. See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/3675 (Feedback is welcome)

Answer (score 1):

If the `Thing` is only available after having built the `host`, then you can do it like this:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{   
   var host = CreateWebHostBuilder(args).UseNLog().Build();
   ConfigureLogging(host.Services.GetAutofacRoot());
   LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger().Info("Hi mom");
   host.Run();
}

private static void ConfigureLogging(IComponentContext container)
{
   var defaultConstructor = ConfigurationItemFactory.Default.CreateInstance;
   ConfigurationItemFactory.Default.CreateInstance.CreateInstance = type =>
   {
      if (type == typeof(MyTarget))
      {
          var thing = new ThingTheTargetNeedsToFunction();
          return new MyTarget(thing);
      }

      return defaultConstructor(type);
   };

   // Reload config and assign the newly reloaded config
   LogManager.Configuration = LogManager.Configuration?.Reload();
}
```

Then make sure that your custom `MyTarget` can handle that it is running in "disabled mode" where `Thing` is unassigned:

```
[Target("MyTarget")] 
public class MyTarget : AsyncTaskTarget
{
   public MyTarget() {}

   public MyTarget(INeedThisThingToFunction thing)
   {
      Thing = thing;
   }

   public INeedThisThingToFunction Thing { get; set; }

   public override await Task WriteAsyncTask(LogEventInfo logEvent, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   {
      if (Thing == null)
         return null; // Handle that `Thing` is unassigned by default-constructor

      await Thing.UseAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
   }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work either. When the ConfigureLogging method runs, the Thing gets set properly in the MyTarget class. But when LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger() runs, the MyTarget.Thing property is null. Is Autofac running in different contexts or threads? Is it just not possible to do what I'm trying to do without resorting to the service locator anti-pattern?

Comment: @DavidBraverman Remember it is `LogManager.Configuration = LogManager.Configuration?.Reload();` and not just `LogManager.Configuration.Reload()`.